# MYSQL LIKE в utf8_general_ci учитывает регистр для русского языка

Tags: mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `name_ru` LIKE '%ноут%';
Результат = 0 записей
```

Запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `name_ru` LIKE '%Ноут%';
Результат = 10 записей
```

Каким образом настроить запрос, чтобы не учитывался регистр?

Comment: Очень странно... возможно, где-то переопределяются дефолтные charset/collation. Проверьте, как поведёт себя `SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `name_ru` LIKE '%ноут%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

Comment: Unrecognized keyword. (near "COLLATE" at position 52)
Unexpected token. (near ""utf8_general_ci"" at position 60)

Comment: Это сообщение генерирует **НЕ** MySQL. Претензии - к используемому инструменту.

Comment: product` тут не хватает кавычки слева, да и вообще везде кавычки разные у вас, что за бред с кавычками? - utf8_general_ci;`